# Trouble with linking Pages in Eclipse from page to page

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to make pages link each other. Just like in the image below. and i am having troubles getting a pages to link down to others and then have the last page link to the original 
Here is a image to give you guys an idea of what im trying to do
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5SXj.png

this is home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/title"
tools:context=".home" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp"
    android:text="@string/page1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:text="@string/page2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:text="@string/page3"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

page1.java

```
    package com.example.app;


     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.text.method.KeyListener;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.text.method.KeyListener;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class page1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);
    }
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void OnStart(){
        Button Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);     
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View Button) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Home.this, page1.class); 
        Home.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            } 

        });
        }
```

Comment: What problems are you running into? What is and is not working? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are in the page1 activity, and your onclick starts an activity for page1. So every time you click the button1, you will be launching the same activity.

This is what I imagine you are trying to accomplish:

```
public class HomePage extends Activity{
...
public void OnStart() {
    Button Btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View Button) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), page1.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    Button Btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View Button) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), page2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    Button Btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View Button) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), page3.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

And you will have similar onClickListeners in your page1, page2, etc activities to navigate further.

Answer (score 0):

try creating your intent like this-

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, page1.class);
```

and then start your activity like

```
Home.this.startActivity use startActivity(myIntent);
```